# How to output plain URL to the node in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I would like to output plain absolute URL of the node from Views as part of my XML feed (via [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource)).

So far I have found the following field handler:

> Content: Link - Provide a simple link to the content.

which is provided by Views it-self, but checking [`views_handler_field_node_link.inc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node!views_handler_field_node_link.inc/7) file doesn't seems to support displaying plain text (and there are no any [field formatters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7), as it's field specific), but instead I've got:

```
<a href="http://localhost/node/123">view</a>
```

without possibility to change the format (apart of the text it-self).

Is there any other way to display just plain URL of the node using Views field handler (without having actual field)?

Comment: is it an option to use Global :Text field and construct URL manually - http:// localhost/node/[content:nid] ? Haven't used Views Datasource, so I'm not sure if this approach will work with its formatting requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Content: Path* works with Drupal 7. Select *Use absolute link (begins with "http://")* in *Rewrite results* section of the field settings.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of Content: Link, use the **Content: Path** field.

Comment: AFIK, That will work for D8 not for D7.

Comment: Content: Path works with D7

Answer (score 0):

Just noting for Drupal 8. In more recent versions of Drupal 8 (e.g 8.8), you can use Content > Link to Content:

> Output the URL as text

[image: link to content]